# using regex output in a method

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regex to read data from a file but I'm having trouble using the data I'm reading. 
here is my code:

```
            File file = new File(eventsFile);
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
                while(sc.hasNext()){
                    String eventLine = sc.nextLine();

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Event=(?<event>[^,]*),time=(?<time>[^,]*)(,rings=(?<rings>[^,]*))?$");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(eventLine);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.print(matcher.group("event") + " " + matcher.group("time"));
                    String eventName = matcher.group("event");
                    int time = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("time"));

                    Class<?> eventClass = Class.forName(eventName);
                    Constructor<?> constructor = eventClass.getConstructor(long.class);
                    Event event = (Event) constructor.newInstance(time);
                    addEvent(event);

                        if (matcher.group(4) != null) {
                            System.out.println(" " + matcher.group(4));
                        } else {
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The print statements are there just temporarily to make sure the scanning of the file and regex work. what i'm trying to accomplish is use `matcher.group(1)` and `matcher.group(2)` as follows `addEvent(new eventname(time))` where `eventname` is `matcher.group(1)` and `time` is `matcher.group(2)`
I tried creating variables to store `group(1)` and 2 and use them in `addEvent` but that didn't really work. So any ideas on how to approach such an issue?

---

EDIT:
Example of text file

```
Event=ThermostatNight,time=0
Event=LightOn,time=2000
Event=WaterOff,time=10000
Event=ThermostatDay,time=12000
Event=Bell,time=9000,rings=5
Event=WaterOn,time=6000
Event=LightOff,time=4000
Event=Terminate,time=20000
Event=FansOn,time=7000
Event=FansOff,time=8000
```

I'm trying to reach a situation where i would be running for an addEvent function for each of these lines in the text file that would follow this example `addEvent(new ThermostatNight(0));`

Comment: _"...but that didn't really work"_ - it is unclear what your actual issue is. What are you trying to achieve and what is happening instead?

Comment: To get better help consider providing examples of (1) input (2) expected output/result and (3) what you get instead. Also please avoid: ["doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: @Marvin so if i wasn't reading the values i needed from a text file i would use `addEvent(new event(delaytime)` where even can be different classes right as the code stands now `matcher.group(1)` is the value of "event" but i can't seem to get addEvent to see the value that matcher.group() is storing hope that clarifies a bit

Comment: So you are trying to dynamically create instances of classes based on text? Look into java reflection.

Comment: @Marvin I looked into java reflection and it's still all new to me so i might be doing something wrong but i used `Class<?> eventClass = Class.forName(eventName);` (I updated the code in my question as well) but the issue is `addEvent is still not accepting eventClass im not entirely sure what i'm missing to make this work